# Change CSS based on URL

Tags: ruby, heroku

We have created a heroku app using ruby and would like to change the css, page title and some content based off of the URL used to access the app.  How would you go about doing that?

Comment: `application.html.erb` can contain ruby code

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague. It would be easier to help if you provided a concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish, and what you have already attempted.